# WS client get "Connection reset" on a Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: java, .net, web-services, iis, ssl

I'm trying to access a webservice with my Java client and I get stuck.

I deployed a .Net WebService on a Windows Server 2012 R2, this webservice uses https over 443 tcp port.
The WebService certificate is installed on the server and is valid.

The Windows Server Event Viewer show me this error messages:

> "A fatal alert was generated and sent to the remote endpoint. This may
>   result in termination of the connection. The TLS protocol defined
>   fatal error code is 40. The Windows SChannel error state is 1205."
>
> "An TLS 1.2 connection request was received from a remote client
>   application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client
>   application are supported by the server. The SSL connection request
>   has failed."

The java client was created by Eclipse with the WSDL from the WebService.
My java client show this log:

> org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: No service named WebService is available
>   org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: **No service named WebService is available**
>     at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getService(FileProvider.java:233)
>     at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getService(AxisEngine.java:311)
>     at org.apache.axis.MessageContext.setTargetService(MessageContext.java:756)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2690)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
>     at wscaller.enviar.WebServiceStub.enviarLoteEventos(WebServiceStub.java:107)
>     at wscaller.enviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosProxy.enviarLoteEventos(ServicoEnviarLoteEventosProxy.java:50)
>     at wscaller.EnviarLoteFacade.runImp(EnviarLoteFacade.java:17)
>     at wscaller.WsFacade.run(WsFacade.java:34)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Run.runUntilSatisfyRequired(Run.java:127)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Run.runImpl(Run.java:72)
>     at functions.v2.teste.ParseRun.runImpl(ParseRun.java:17)
>     at functions.v2.ToolOperation.runImpl(ToolOperation.java:30)
>     at functions.ProcessOperation.run(ProcessOperation.java:22)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Auto.runImpl(Auto.java:39)
>     at functions.ProcessOperation.run(ProcessOperation.java:22)
>     at ToolMain.main(ToolMain.java:79)
>
> at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getService(FileProvider.java:233)
>     at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getService(AxisEngine.java:311)
>     at org.apache.axis.MessageContext.setTargetService(MessageContext.java:756)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2690)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
>     at wscaller.enviar.WebServiceStub.enviarLoteEventos(WebServiceStub.java:107)
>     at wscaller.enviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosProxy.enviarLoteEventos(ServicoEnviarLoteEventosProxy.java:50)
>     at wscaller.EnviarLoteFacade.runImp(EnviarLoteFacade.java:17)
>     at wscaller.WsFacade.run(WsFacade.java:34)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Run.runUntilSatisfyRequired(Run.java:127)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Run.runImpl(Run.java:72)
>     at functions.v2.teste.ParseRun.runImpl(ParseRun.java:17)
>     at functions.v2.ToolOperation.runImpl(ToolOperation.java:30)
>     at functions.ProcessOperation.run(ProcessOperation.java:22)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Auto.runImpl(Auto.java:39)
>     at functions.ProcessOperation.run(ProcessOperation.java:22)
>     at ToolMain.main(ToolMain.java:79)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG MessageContext:793 - MessageContext: setServiceHandler(null)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(targetService)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG Call:2715 - Target service:  WebService
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG MessageContext:749 - MessageContext: setTargetService(http://www.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/lote/eventos/envio/v1_0_0/ServicoEnviarLoteEventos/EnviarLoteEventos)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(noService10)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ConfigurationException:110 - Exception: 
>   org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: No service named http://www.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/lote/eventos/envio/v1_0_0/ServicoEnviarLoteEventos/EnviarLoteEventos is available
>   org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: No service named http://www.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/lote/eventos/envio/v1_0_0/ServicoEnviarLoteEventos/EnviarLoteEventos is available
>     at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getService(FileProvider.java:233)
>     at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getService(AxisEngine.java:311)
>     at org.apache.axis.MessageContext.setTargetService(MessageContext.java:756)
>     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPTransport.setupMessageContextImpl(HTTPTransport.java:89)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Transport.setupMessageContext(Transport.java:46)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2738)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
>     at wscaller.enviar.WebServiceStub.enviarLoteEventos(WebServiceStub.java:107)
>     at wscaller.enviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosProxy.enviarLoteEventos(ServicoEnviarLoteEventosProxy.java:50)
>     at wscaller.EnviarLoteFacade.runImp(EnviarLoteFacade.java:17)
>     at wscaller.WsFacade.run(WsFacade.java:34)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Run.runUntilSatisfyRequired(Run.java:127)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Run.runImpl(Run.java:72)
>     at functions.v2.teste.ParseRun.runImpl(ParseRun.java:17)
>     at functions.v2.ToolOperation.runImpl(ToolOperation.java:30)
>     at functions.ProcessOperation.run(ProcessOperation.java:22)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Auto.runImpl(Auto.java:39)
>     at functions.ProcessOperation.run(ProcessOperation.java:22)
>     at ToolMain.main(ToolMain.java:79)
>
> at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getService(FileProvider.java:233)
>     at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getService(AxisEngine.java:311)
>     at org.apache.axis.MessageContext.setTargetService(MessageContext.java:756)
>     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPTransport.setupMessageContextImpl(HTTPTransport.java:89)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Transport.setupMessageContext(Transport.java:46)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2738)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
>     at wscaller.enviar.WebServiceStub.enviarLoteEventos(WebServiceStub.java:107)
>     at wscaller.enviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosProxy.enviarLoteEventos(ServicoEnviarLoteEventosProxy.java:50)
>     at wscaller.EnviarLoteFacade.runImp(EnviarLoteFacade.java:17)
>     at wscaller.WsFacade.run(WsFacade.java:34)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Run.runUntilSatisfyRequired(Run.java:127)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Run.runImpl(Run.java:72)
>     at functions.v2.teste.ParseRun.runImpl(ParseRun.java:17)
>     at functions.v2.ToolOperation.runImpl(ToolOperation.java:30)
>     at functions.ProcessOperation.run(ProcessOperation.java:22)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Auto.runImpl(Auto.java:39)
>     at functions.ProcessOperation.run(ProcessOperation.java:22)
>     at ToolMain.main(ToolMain.java:79)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG MessageContext:793 - MessageContext: setServiceHandler(null)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SOAPPart:661 - Enter: SOAPPart::getAsSOAPEnvelope()
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(currForm)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SOAPPart:662 - current form is FORM_SOAPENVELOPE
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(register00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:472 - register 'soapenv' - 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(register00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:472 - register 'soapenv' - 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(register00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:472 - register 'xsd' - 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(register00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:472 - register 'xsi' - 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(startElem00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:1098 - Start element [http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/]:Envelope
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(startElem00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:1098 - Start element [http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/]:Body
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(register00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:472 - register '' - 'http://www.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/lote/eventos/envio/v1_0_0'
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(startElem00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:1098 - Start element [http://www.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/lote/eventos/envio/v1_0_0]:EnviarLoteEventos
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(startElem00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:1098 - Start element [http://www.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/lote/eventos/envio/v1_0_0]:loteEventos
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(endElem00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:1208 - End element loteEventos
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(endElem00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:1208 - End element EnviarLoteEventos
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(endElem00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:1208 - End element soapenv:Body
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(endElem00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:1208 - End element soapenv:Envelope
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG Call:2762 - *Omitido para diminuir o tamanho*
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG AxisClient:77 - Enter: AxisClient::invoke
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG AxisClient:90 - EngineHandler: null
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(axisUserAgent)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SimpleChain:79 - Enter: SimpleChain::invoke
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(enter00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG HTTPSender:125 - Enter:  HTTPSender::invoke
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SOAPPart:524 - Enter: SOAPPart::saveChanges
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(register00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:472 - register 'soapenv' - 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(register00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:472 - register 'soapenv' - 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(register00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:472 - register 'xsd' - 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(register00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:472 - register 'xsi' - 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(startElem00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:1098 - Start element [http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/]:Envelope
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(startElem00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:1098 - Start element [http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/]:Body
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(register00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:472 - register '' - 'http://www.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/lote/eventos/envio/v1_0_0'
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(startElem00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:1098 - Start element [http://www.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/lote/eventos/envio/v1_0_0]:EnviarLoteEventos
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(startElem00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:1098 - Start element [http://www.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/lote/eventos/envio/v1_0_0]:loteEventos
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(endElem00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:1208 - End element loteEventos
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(endElem00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:1208 - End element EnviarLoteEventos
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(endElem00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:1208 - End element soapenv:Body
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(endElem00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SerializationContext:1208 - End element soapenv:Envelope
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(setMsgForm)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SOAPPart:374 - Setting current message form to: FORM_OPTIMIZED (currentMessage is now org.apache.axis.utils.ByteArray)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SOAPPart:537 - Exit: SOAPPart::saveChanges(): org.apache.axis.utils.ByteArray@1ca7889
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SOAPPart:524 - Enter: SOAPPart::saveChanges
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SOAPPart:524 - Enter: SOAPPart::saveChanges
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG HTTPSender:146 - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SOAPPart:182 - Enter: SOAPPart ctor(FORM_FAULT)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(setMsgForm)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SOAPPart:374 - Setting current message form to: FORM_FAULT (currentMessage is now org.apache.axis.AxisFault)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG SOAPPart:188 - Exit: SOAPPart ctor()
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ProjectResourceBundle:72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(toAxisFault00)
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG enterprise:2445 - Mapping Exception to AxisFault
>   AxisFault
>    faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
>    faultSubcode: 
>    faultString: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>    faultActor: 
>    faultNode: 
>    faultDetail: 
>     {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
>     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
>     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
>     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
>     at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
>     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
>     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
>     at wscaller.enviar.WebServiceStub.enviarLoteEventos(WebServiceStub.java:107)
>     at wscaller.enviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosProxy.enviarLoteEventos(ServicoEnviarLoteEventosProxy.java:50)
>     at wscaller.EnviarLoteFacade.runImp(EnviarLoteFacade.java:17)
>     at wscaller.WsFacade.run(WsFacade.java:34)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Run.runUntilSatisfyRequired(Run.java:127)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Run.runImpl(Run.java:72)
>     at functions.v2.teste.ParseRun.runImpl(ParseRun.java:17)
>     at functions.v2.ToolOperation.runImpl(ToolOperation.java:30)
>     at functions.ProcessOperation.run(ProcessOperation.java:22)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Auto.runImpl(Auto.java:39)
>     at functions.ProcessOperation.run(ProcessOperation.java:22)
>     at ToolMain.main(ToolMain.java:79)
>
> {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:1525078
>
> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>     at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
>     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:154)
>     at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
>     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
>     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
>     at wscaller.enviar.WebServiceStub.enviarLoteEventos(WebServiceStub.java:107)
>     at wscaller.enviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosProxy.enviarLoteEventos(ServicoEnviarLoteEventosProxy.java:50)
>     at wscaller.EnviarLoteFacade.runImp(EnviarLoteFacade.java:17)
>     at wscaller.WsFacade.run(WsFacade.java:34)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Run.runUntilSatisfyRequired(Run.java:127)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Run.runImpl(Run.java:72)
>     at functions.v2.teste.ParseRun.runImpl(ParseRun.java:17)
>     at functions.v2.ToolOperation.runImpl(ToolOperation.java:30)
>     at functions.ProcessOperation.run(ProcessOperation.java:22)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Auto.runImpl(Auto.java:39)
>     at functions.ProcessOperation.run(ProcessOperation.java:22)
>     at ToolMain.main(ToolMain.java:79)
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
>     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
>     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
>     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
>     ... 21 more
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 DEBUG ToolProperties:73 - ; nested exception is: 
>     java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>   AxisFault
>    faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
>    faultSubcode: 
>    faultString: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>    faultActor: 
>    faultNode: 
>    faultDetail: 
>     {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
>     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
>     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
>     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
>     at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
>     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
>     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
>     at wscaller.enviar.WebServiceStub.enviarLoteEventos(WebServiceStub.java:107)
>     at wscaller.enviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosProxy.enviarLoteEventos(ServicoEnviarLoteEventosProxy.java:50)
>     at wscaller.EnviarLoteFacade.runImp(EnviarLoteFacade.java:17)
>     at wscaller.WsFacade.run(WsFacade.java:34)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Run.runUntilSatisfyRequired(Run.java:127)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Run.runImpl(Run.java:72)
>     at functions.v2.teste.ParseRun.runImpl(ParseRun.java:17)
>     at functions.v2.ToolOperation.runImpl(ToolOperation.java:30)
>     at functions.ProcessOperation.run(ProcessOperation.java:22)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Auto.runImpl(Auto.java:39)
>     at functions.ProcessOperation.run(ProcessOperation.java:22)
>     at ToolMain.main(ToolMain.java:79)
>
> {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:1525078
>
> java.net.SocketException: **Connection reset**
>     at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
>     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:154)
>     at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
>     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
>     at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
>     at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
>     at wscaller.enviar.WebServiceStub.enviarLoteEventos(WebServiceStub.java:107)
>     at wscaller.enviar.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosProxy.enviarLoteEventos(ServicoEnviarLoteEventosProxy.java:50)
>     at wscaller.EnviarLoteFacade.runImp(EnviarLoteFacade.java:17)
>     at wscaller.WsFacade.run(WsFacade.java:34)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Run.runUntilSatisfyRequired(Run.java:127)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Run.runImpl(Run.java:72)
>     at functions.v2.teste.ParseRun.runImpl(ParseRun.java:17)
>     at functions.v2.ToolOperation.runImpl(ToolOperation.java:30)
>     at functions.ProcessOperation.run(ProcessOperation.java:22)
>     at functions.v2.teste.Auto.runImpl(Auto.java:39)
>     at functions.ProcessOperation.run(ProcessOperation.java:22)
>     at ToolMain.main(ToolMain.java:79)
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: **Connection reset**
>     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
>     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
>     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
>     at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
>     ... 21 more
>   2015-06-15 13:19:18 INFO  ToolProperties:143 - Problema no WebService: ; nested exception is: 
>     java.net.SocketException: **Connection reset**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to alter the server regedit

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Cryptography\Configuration\Local\SSL\00010003

Add a value to the key Functions:

> RSA/SHA512

http://blogs.technet.com/b/silvana/archive/2014/03/14/schannel-errors-on-scom-agent.aspx